# dynamic url crawl using python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Using python scrapy i am able to crawl single static url but how to crawl dynamic url?
like https://www.britannica.com/place/Mumbai, https://www.britannica.com/place/Pune like wise.

**Working Code for Single Static Page**

```
import scrapy 
class GetTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "testspeder"
    start_urls = ["https://www.britannica.com/place/Mumbai"]

    def parse(self,response):
    """Function to process search results page"""
    for site in response.xpath("//div[@class='infinite-pagination-container container']"):
        item = {
            'city': site.xpath(".//h1/text()").extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'writtenby': site.xpath(".//div[@class='md-byline']/div[@class='written-by']/span/text()").extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'alternativename': site.xpath(".//div[@class='md-alternate-titles']/text()").extract_first(default='').strip(),
        }
        yield item
```

Comment: your code works fine with multiple entries of place, what else do you want to achieve?

Comment: @chrisckwong821, please check updated question

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: @Gallaecio, based on the above tutorial I have created a demo.

Comment: What is not working on it? What have you tried so far to overcome it?

Comment: @Gallaecio, you can check my try above code, for static url I am ableto fetch data. but for dynamic url something is wrong, and no error listed, you can check stack trace which is given above.

Comment: Looks like a problem in `"//div[@class='eight columns']/ul/li"`. Try with a different XPath expression, or write `response.text` to a file to inspect its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can yield a Request in your `parse` function.

This Request will be then handled by other one, like:

```py
<your parse()>
...
if item["url_addres"]:
    yield Request(
        url=item["url_addres"], 
        callback=self.your_func_for_parsing, 
        meta={
            'item': item, 
            'dont_redirect': True,
            'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]
            }
    )

def your_func_for_parsing(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    ...
    <do the job>
```

Comment: Any Trace Stack? What the problem actually is?

Comment: the problem is no data fetched when i run "scrapy crawl getpincodespider_xpath -o test1.json" , please check updated question with trace stack

Comment: All seems to be good - please check if `response.xpath("//div[@class='eight columns']/ul/li")` gives you any result. Webpage that you scrap withpincodes `["304210", "304230"]` do not have anything here. Check that with webrowser.

Comment: it is working fine, xpath is not an issue, please check my working code for static url.

Comment: Go to the: https://www.getpincode.info/pincode/394210 (from your static) - there are many results.

Go to the: https://www.getpincode.info/pincode/304210 (from your dynamic) - No results there. No records that can be scrapped.